# PEP conform click usage

Tags: python, pylint

I read at the moment some code which violates the pylint design patterns:

- too-many-arguments (R0913)
- too-many-locals (R0914)

by using the decorators of the click package, shown in the example below:

```py
@click.command(help="Run this package on a file")
@click.argument("filename", default="test")
@click.option("--option1", default=1)
@click.option("--option2", default=1)
@click.option("--option3", default=1)
@click.option("--option4", default=1)
@click.option("--option5", default=1)
def main(
    filename,
    option1,
    option2,
    option3,
    option4,
    option5,
    option6,
    option7,
    option8,
    option9,
    option10,
    option11,
    option12,
    option13,
    option14,
    option15,
):
    pass
```

Is their any conform way to create this function without triggering the design pattern warnings?

I now about argument parsing, but I want to know, if their is a reasonable way to use this package. And of course disabling the warnings is also not the goal.

Comment: I'm a pylint maintener and not a click expert that could propose a better design, which is why this is a comment and not an answer. pylint only tell you that something is a code smell, often you need to think about it. Disabling the warning is a perfectly valid solution if following pylint guidance would make the code worse. (Using **kwargs  makes pylint not raise because pylint won't understand the code as well and can't count the number of args, but it's also harder to understand for you, and your code will be worse).

Comment: I really appreciate the way pylint shows me bad code smell. The first time I saw this specific code I smelled bad code design already, but I was wondering if it is possible to work with the package click and keep good code smell. The awnser from @Matthew Wisdom seems as you say work around the pylint warning instead of handling the problem. I might switch to proper argument handling, if I start refactoring the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword argument syntax

```
@click.command(help="Run this package on a file")
@click.argument("filename", default="test")
@click.option("--option1", default=1)
@click.option("--option2", default=1)
@click.option("--option3", default=1)
@click.option("--option4", default=1)
@click.option("--option5", default=1)
def main(
    filename,
    **kwargs
):
    pass
```

Then access the arguments from the `kwargs` dictionary.